# Setting a selectoption value on pageblockTable rerender

Tags: visualforce

I have an PageBlockTable which has a wrapper class as its value.

Every time a command button is clicked to add a product, a new row is added to the wrapper class and the PageblockTable is rerendered to display the new row. All these work but when the rerender happens the selectedValue in the selectList is reset to the first item on the selectList.

How can i have the selectList to maintain state?

```
    <apex:commandButton action="{!addNewProduct}" value="Add New Product" rerender="pbtExistingInstItems,PBCopyProdToInstItems"/>
    <apex:selectList id="slprodname" value="{!itw.installedItem.Product__c}" size="1" rendered="{!itw.isManuallyCreated ==  true}" >
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!prodList}"/>
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!updateDefaultProductValues}"  rerender="colInstallationName">
                </apex:actionSupport>
    </apex:selectList>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you use sObjects picklist instead prodList? Is Product__c a picklist or a sting?

Comment: its not a picklist.. its lookup to product, but i just wanted a few products to be displayed which i am displaying from a custom setting

Comment: I think it is not possible to hold selected values after reRendering, unless you use sObject as container or holds values in an javascript array.

Comment: What do you think would be the best way to handle this scenario? I need to show in few product names for users to choose from, have to capture their IDs and place it in a field called product__c.

Comment: Do you have any sObject where products are stored as a picklist?

Comment: no.. but i can create a field for that

Comment: If you will do it - you could create a dummy object in your code to hold the user input for the products.

Comment: Done. I hope it help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just want to explain my solution. Lets say you have some custom object "SomeObject" and a picklist field "ProductList__c" on that, where are all products collected. And you have a wrapper class. All you need is to add a copy of "SomeObject" to every row. And then at your page it could be like this:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!addNewProduct}" value="Add New Product" rerender="pbtExistingInstItems,PBCopyProdToInstItems"/>

<apex:inputField value="{!itw.SomeObject.ProductList__c}" rendered="{!itw.isManuallyCreated}" id="slprodname">
    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!updateDefaultProductValues}"  rerender="colInstallationName">
</apex:inputField>
```

The picklist `itw.SomeObject.ProductList__c` will be rendered as a normal lelect list where  selected value will be stored even if you re-renders the pageblock.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which kind of pagereference you return from your action method addNewProduct

If you are returning full URL then it loads the whole page, that's why it is reloading and reset to first item in select list.

So use only partial page load, return partial URL.

```
PageReference pr = new PageReference('/apex/PageName'); // for partial page load.

return pr; // use this
```

```
PageReference pr = new PageReference(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/apex/PageName'); // for full page load.

return pr; //don't use this.
```

Comment: i just do a rerender, no pageRef

Comment: Its the same page which gets refreshed and its done using rerender tag. So there is no need of any pageRefs in this instance